# How to access an object's NSDocument?

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument

I can access an *app-wide delegate instance* using `[NSApp delegate]` after adding an `NSObject` to the mainmenu.xib, setting the name of the object to the name of my appDelegate and setting the mainmenu.xib delegate to this object.

Now, what I would like to do, is to access to an object's **Document**, i.e. the active `NSDocument` that the object "belongs" to. It would be a *doc-wide delegate instance* I guess. Sometimes `[self document]` works, but not always. Is there a generic way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to pass a reference explicitly. You may access the document from `NSViewController` in the following way:

```
id document = self.view.window.windowController.document;
```

Comment: ... and judging by the path, I should be able to do this in `init`, right?

Comment: No, your view should be related to some window. Only then you can access that window's controller.

Comment: Forgive my greenness, but... I instantiate a viewcontroller from myDocument. The new window is shown only when I request it, so would `windowControllerDidLoadNib:` be the right place?

Comment: I believe it is not very good idea to create a `viewController` in the `NSDocument` subclass which should be responsible for data. The best place to create a view controller and insert its view into the window would be `-[NSWindowController loadWindow]`. Later, you can access the view from `NSDocument` as `self.mainWindowController.contentViewController.view`.

Answer (score 1):

What about `[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] currentDocument]` ?

Be careful nevertheless.
Please read 
[NSDocumentController currentDocument returning nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912314/nsdocumentcontroller-currentdocument-returning-nil)

Answer (score 0):

For any sub windows that are part of the document, it turns out that it's very easy to make a very simple subclass of `NSViewController` and store the required information in there. These view controllers are set up within the main Document implementation so it is easy to pass the address of the `NSDocument` object. Any actual subview can then be controlled by a view controller that is a subclass of this "managing controller".

This solution does not work for *every* object, but it does take the biggest hurdle and solves my problem...